# How to open word document with known password using applescript?

Tags: ms-word, passwords, applescript

I need to open a protected Microsoft Word document via AppleScript.
I know the password, but i can't figure out how to code it with AppleScript.

I tried some variations of AppleScript code, without success.

```
set the myfile to ("/Users/alemac/Desktop/teste.docx")
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    open myfile password document "123"
end tell
```

Word opens the file (like Finder does), and the password dialog opens waiting for password.

Answer (score 0):

After running your version of the AppleScript code several times, the command `open myfile password document`  actually worked for me maybe 3 or 4 sporadic times.  Eventually it stopped working and the password dialog box opened every time.  After wracking my brain trying to figure out why this was happening, for nearly an hour, I reluctantly decided to use UI scripting to handle the password dialog box, in the event it reared its ugly head.

This AppleScript code works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave and Microsoft Word version 16.24

```
set the myfile to (path to desktop as text) & "teste.docx"
set thePassword to 123

tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    ignoring application responses
        open myfile password document thePassword
        delay 1
    end ignoring
end tell

try
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat until exists of window "Password" of application process "Word"
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        click window "Password" of application process "Word"
        delay 0.2
        click text field 1 of window "Password" of application process "Word"
        delay 0.2
        keystroke thePassword
        delay 0.2
        keystroke return
    end tell
end try
```